# How to convert enum type into string while serialization

Tags: enums, json-serialization

While Json Serialization I got below result:

```
{ "Action": 0 }
```

But I want to change the result as string instead of 0

```
{ "Action": "Include" }

public enum FAction
{
        Include = 0,
}
```

I have property using this Enum.

```
public FAction Action { get; set; }

//...
Action = FAction.Include;
//...
```

I have used like this. To get the following  result

```
{ "Action": "Include" }
```

what I have to do? Please, suggest any.